# Interoperability between webserver RMI

Tags: java, servlets, rmi

I have a TCP/RMI server to communicate with a web server running Apache tomcat, and all information, eg customers is stored on the TCP/RMI server. This is all done in java (tcp sockets, Java RMI, servlets, JavaBeans, JSP, comet).

Communication between the two servers is done by RMI.

The web clients make requests to the http web server, which forwards them to the server TCP / RMI. So far so good.

The problem is the reverse communication, the server TCP / RMI to web server. As the connection between servers is performed by RMI you can send a callback by the web server as it does for asynchronous communication between client and server rmi?

Regards,
André

Answer (score -1):

It's possible for 2 way communcation by providing an callback object that the server can call. You can also , just run 2 RMI servers. 1 on your TCP server, and the other 1 on your Tomcat. Thus also creating an bidirectional communication link. You can use static methods and a contextlistener to start you RMI server on your TomCat.

I'm currently working on a similar project, with Glassfish, RMI bidirectional communication, Comet and others. This is my RMI server class in the web app. Might give you some inspiration.

```
package RMI.WS;

import ILWS.Controller.Comet.CometServlet;
import Logging.DSLogger;
import RMI.DSRMI;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;

/**
 *
 * @author roy
 */
public class RMIServer implements Runnable {

    private static final String rmiPath = "ILWServlet";
    private static final String ClientrmiPath = "ILDS";
    private static RemoteInteractor interactor;
    private static DSRMI rmiClient;
    private static RMIServer rmi;
    private static int rmiPort;

    public static void startRMI() {
        rmiPort = 6666;
        try {
            interactor = new RemoteInteractor();
            LocateRegistry.createRegistry(rmiPort).rebind(rmiPath, interactor);
            DSLogger.Debug(RMIServer.class, "creating new RMI Registry");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            DSLogger.Log(RMIServer.class, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void stopRMI() {
        try {
            LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1", rmiPort).unbind("ILWServlet");
            DSLogger.Debug(RMIServer.class, "removing RMI Registry");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            DSLogger.throwableLog(RMIServer.class, ex);
        }
    }

    public static DSRMI getClientRMI() {
        if (rmiClient == null) {
            try {
                rmiClient = (DSRMI) LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1", 6665).lookup(ClientrmiPath);
            } catch (NotBoundException ex) {
                DSLogger.throwableLog(RMIServer.class, ex);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                DSLogger.throwableLog(RMIServer.class, ex);
            }
        }
        return rmiClient;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thu Rmi communication can be at both sides if you send a callback to the server (a remote reference from the client to the server).

Comment: This answer is simply incorrect. The client can export a callback object that the server can call.

Comment: EJP, could you also please provide an example?

Comment: @rkokkelk the example is just a remote object created in the client. Pass it to the server as a parameter, specifying the remote interface as the formal argument type. Then the server can call remote methods on that object, firewalls and Internet permitting of course.